# Filter The json array using jolt spec

Tags: json, jolt

We need to filter the records: if both are the same, then reject; if ***different***, we need to *output them*

```json
[
  {
    "item": 2,
    "code": 23,
    "modelcode": 23
  },
  {
    "item": 2,
    "code": 23,
    "modelcode": 24
  }
]
```

output should be

```json
[
  {
    "item": 2,
    "code": 23,
    "modelcode": 24
  }
]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reject! It seems what you want is basically to remove duplicates is that correct? Is any of the values considered unique or the combination of all of them make the record unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the equality of both attributes through use of size whenever they're matched one by one, whether equal to 2 which will mean they're different( the value 1 means they're identical ).

So, you can use the following transformation :

```json
[
  {// generate new object cmn in order to get whether it has one or two elements
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "#common": ["&1.cmn.@1,modelcode", "&1.cmn.@1,code"]
      }
    }
  },
  {// measure the sizes for newly generated objects respectively
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cmn": "=size"
      }
    }
  },
  {// separate by those sizes 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,cmn.&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {// filter by the size 2 in order to get the objects with different values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "2": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of the extra identifier which is "cmn"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "cmn": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The more *straightforward* case follows as an alternative :

```json
[
  { // partition the objects by both of those values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@1,modelcode.@1,code.&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "&": { // matching ones
          "*": {
            "": "" // < skip this case >
          }
        },
        "*": { // non-matching ones
          "*": {
             "@": "[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That  straightforward way is very nice . I would not think about it in a million year :) because It seems counter intuitive to the spec since as it looks you are using & in LHS and the spec is clear on it to be for RHS (https://docs.digibee.com/documentation/components/tools/transformer-jolt/transformer-getting-to-know-jolt#and). I kind of understand what you are doing but Im surprised its working. I guess that why they call you the jolt master :)

Comment: My pleasure , but I was hoping you explain to me why & is valid in the LHS in this case :)? Also why you prefer to reference out of scope value as in @1,modelcode without using ( ) as in @(1,modelcode), to me the later looks clearer and as one thing? is this jolt recommendation or your personal preference?

Comment: I didn't meet any documented fact for those, just tried and catched :) in order to shorten the code @samersaleh